# Which version of Windows phone 7 is called 'Mango'?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Which version of Windows phone 7 is called 'Mango'? Is it windows phone 7.5?

Answer (score 8):

Windows Phone 7.1 is the version of the SDK for Mango application development.
Windows Phone 7.5 is the consumer facing version number for the new operating system.

Comment: It's similar to Windows in that Windows 7 is actually Windows 6.1. The difference is that most developers will likely refer to Mango as 7.1 (due to it being referenced that way in the docs), but Windows 7 developers wouldn't call it Windows 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Codenames and marketing names seem to differ but, Mango is either WP 7.1 or 7.5.

See: [Windows Phone version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history)

7.1 is the actual version number (internal), 7.5 seems to be the official marketed version.

Answer (score 1):

As Far As I Know, Windows Phone 7.1 is having code name 'Mango'.